# If $L\mid K$ is finite not separable then the pairing $\langle x,y\rangle =T_{L\mid K}(xy)$ is degenerate

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ over $K$ be a finite not separable extension of fields. I want to prove that
$$\langle x,y\rangle:=T_{L\mid K}(xy)$$
is degenerate, i.e. there exists a nonzero $x\in L$ such that $\langle x, L\rangle =0$, meaning that $\langle x,y\rangle =0$ for every $y\in L$.

Following my textbook, from not-separability follos that $K$ has positive prime characteristic $p$ and there is a subfield $F$ of $L$ with $K\subseteq F\subseteq L$ and

1) $\operatorname{dim}_F L=[L:F]=p^m$, for some $m\geq 1$

2) for each $x\in L, x^p\in F$.

We prove that $\langle x,L\rangle =0$ for every $x\in L$ that is not in $F$. Fix attention on a given $x$ in $L$ but not in $F$ and let $y\in L$. Suppose first that $xy\notin F$. Then the minimal polynomial of $xy$ over $F$ is $t^p-a$ for some $a\in F$. The characteristic polynomial of $xy$ over $F$ must be
$$(t^p-a)^{p^{m-1}}$$
I can't understand why characteristic polynomial should have this form. I recall that characteristic polynomial of $x\in L$ is defined as
$$f(t):=\det(t\cdot\mathbb{1}_n-r_x)$$
where $r_x$ is the $K$-endomorphism of $L$ sending $y$ to $xy$.

Thanks for any help or suggenstion.

Comment: See the proof of Theorem 1.1 at http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable2.pdf

Comment: @KCd Thanks for reference

Comment: In the second sentence of your question, you want to say the pairing is degenerate, *not* "not degenerate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a basic linear algebra fact that for a matrix $M \in M_n(K)$ -- here $K$ is any field -- then the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $M$ have the same irreducible factors (but possibly with different multiplicities).  Thus if the minimal polynomial is a power of an irreducible polynomial, so is the characteristic polynomial.

This happens in the case you're asking about: in characteristic $p$, $t^p - a = (t-b)^p$ if there is $b \in K$ with $b^p = a$; if not, $t^p - a$ is irreducible: see $\S$ 6.1 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/FieldTheory.pdf).  (The non/degeneracy of the trace form is treated in $\S$ 7 of *loc. cit.*, but looking back there is one Corollary there for which the above fact is implicitly used.  I guess there is some room for improvement in the exposition here.)

Comment: L.Clark sorry for the ignorant question, but....why there's not such $b$ in my case?

Comment: @Federica: The minimal polynomial of an element $\alpha$ in a finite field extension is always irreducible: if $f(\alpha) = 0$ and $f = gh$, then either $g(\alpha) = 0$ or $h(\alpha)  = 0$.  (But even if $t^p-a$ is reducible, it is still a power of an irreducible polynomial, which would be enough to answer your question.)